# How to get mean of filtered dataframe

Tags: python

I have to filter dark chocolate with yes and find mean of no of chocolate which is filtered after applying filter of "yes". Data Frame filtered and now i want to get mean(average) of filtered data. but when i use mean function it gives average of all data without filtering.
name  dark chocolate   no of chocolate
a       yes                10
b       no                 5
c       yes                20

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result. Read and apply [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

I think after filtering all the 'yes' values, you didn't save your dataframe to a new value. I think you tried calculating the mean something like this:

`import pandas as pd
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': ['yes', 'no', 'yes' ], 'b': [10,  5, 20]})
df[df.a == 'yes']
df.b.mean()`

Please write your second line this way:

`df = df[df.a == 'yes']
df.b.mean()`

It should work fine!